# Text To Speech not working as expected in my android application

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

This is the code that I have written.

```
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (j < 10) {
                            if(j == 0) {
                                speaker.speak("Forwards",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
                                //Log.d("XXYYZZ", String.valueOf(j));
                            }
                            show.setImageResource(0);
                            show.setImageResource(images[j+1]);
                            j++;
                        }
                        else if(j == 10){
                            speaker.speak("Backwards",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
                            j++;
                        }

                        else if (j < 19) {
                            show.setImageResource(0);
                            show.setImageResource(images[j+1]);
                            j++;
                        }
                        if (i++ < 94)
                        {
                            if(j ==19)
                                j = 0;
                            //Log.d("XXYYZZ", String.valueOf(j));
                            handler.postDelayed(this, 300);
                        }
                        else {
                            speaker.setSpeechRate(2.0f);
                            speaker.speak("Relax!",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
                            Toast.makeText(CurrentWorkoutActivity.this, "Workout Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                };
                handler.post(runnable);
```

I am using handlers to cause delays.

Here I am trying that whenever the value of variable j is reset to zero, the speaker (TextToSpeech object) speaks "Forwards". But it speaks for the first run only.

Whenever j becomes 10 it does speak "Backwards". Please explain the error or the concept.

I have tried debugging using logcat and the value of j becomes zero as expected but it just doesn't speak.
I tried to search a lot but got no relevant documentation or question.

I'm a beginner in android development and sorry if this turns out to be a stupid question.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

Worked on placing the if statement out of the outer if.